# Intermittent "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" error

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've just started using requirejs and I'm having a problem that I can't seem to solve.  I am occasional getting error "Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery" when I load my application.  Here are the pertinent files:

.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="./css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/vendor/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

my require.config from main.js file:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : './scripts',
    shim : {
        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        },

        bootstrap : {
            dep : [ 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Bootstrap'
        },

        backbone : {
            deps : [ 'jquery', 'underscore' ],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        },

        marionette : {
            deps : [ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone' ],
            exports : 'Marionette'
        },

        text: {
            deps : [ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone' ],
            exports: 'Text'
        }
    },

    paths : {
        jquery : 'vendor/jquery.min',
        underscore : 'vendor/underscore',
        bootstrap : 'vendor/bootstrap.min',
        backbone : 'vendor/backbone',
        marionette : 'vendor/backbone.marionette',
        text: 'vendor/text'
    }
});
```

As I say, this doesn't happen all the time, just randomly.  Can someone see what I'm doing wrong or how I might be able to track down the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this part of your config:

```
bootstrap : {
            dep : [ 'jquery'],
```

It should be `deps` not `dep`. With `dep`, it is as if you had not specified any dependencies at all, which means that Bootstrap will load fine only if jQuery *happens* to be loaded before it. (Also, Bootstrap does not define a `Bootstrap` symbol so the `exports` bit is useless.)

Comment: Damn man, 6 months I've had that bug hiding in my shim! Thanks a ton.

Comment: This works, but shouldn't Shims only be used for non AMD modules?

Comment: @Legends Yes, you are correct, but Bootstrap is not an AMD module. So it needs a `shim.